# How to compute $\int_0^{\infty} x^{t-1} e^{-x}\ln(x)\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have hit the following integral (in the process of trying to derive a finite-sample correction for the Maximum Likelihood fitting of the Generalized Extreme Value distribution...):

$$\int_0^{\infty} x^{t-1}  e^{-x}\ln(x)\,dx$$

It's a sort of cross between a definition of the $\Gamma$ function and an Euler-Mascheroni integral. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}\,dx$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By definition, we know that
$$
\Gamma(t)= \int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}\,dx
$$
then our problem is simply the first derivative of gamma function w.r.t. variable $t$
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}\ln x\,dx=\frac{d}{dt} \Gamma(t)=\Gamma(t)\cdot\psi(t)
$$
where $\psi(t)$ is the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Answer (score 3):

Expanding Daniel Fischer's comment,
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{t-1}e^{-x}\log x\,dx = \frac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{t-1}e^{-x}\,dx = \frac{d}{dt}\Gamma(t) = \psi(t)\cdot\Gamma(t) $$
where $\psi(t)$ is the [digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html):
$$\psi(t)=-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{t-1}{n(n+t-1)}.$$

Comment: Of course! Thank you both.